# What is the name of the quick open completion setting in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, themes

I want to change the theme color for this particular element (the bright white letter when searching in quick open, ex: **tab**Completion in the screenshot).

I cannot find it in the settings. Does someone know its setting name ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That highlighted foreground color for the found typed letters is:

```
editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground
editorSuggestWidget.focusHighlightForeground  // when that line is selected
```

From [theme colors: editor widgets](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-widget-colors)